# VBA to Paste as value and loop through specific sheets

Tags: excel, vba, return-value, copy-paste, paste

I need my code to copy and paste values from only 2 specific sheets "Pro Rate" & "Weekly Labor" These two sheets have the same 9 columns that I want copied over.

The problem is my code is copying all 20+ sheets and pasting with formulas so essentially I get all NAs

I've tried using a code:

```
Public Sub CombineDataFromAllSheets()

    Dim wksSrc As Worksheet, wksDst As Worksheet
    Dim rngSrc As Range, rngDst As Range
    Dim lngLastCol As Long, lngSrcLastRow As Long, lngDstLastRow As Long

    'Notes: "Src" is short for "Source", "Dst" is short for "Destination"
    Set wksDst = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Import")
    lngDstLastRow = LastOccupiedRowNum(wksDst)

    Set rngDst = wksDst.Cells(2, 1)

    For Each wksSrc In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
     If wksSrc.Name <> "Import" Then
    lngSrcLastRow = LastOccupiedRowNum(wksSrc)

    With wksSrc
    Set rngSrc = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lngSrcLastRow, 9))
    rngSrc.Copy Destination:=rngDst
    End With
            lngDstLastRow = LastOccupiedRowNum(wksDst)
            Set rngDst = wksDst.Cells(lngDstLastRow + 1, 1)

    End If
      Next wksSrc


End Sub

Public Function LastOccupiedRowNum(Sheet As Worksheet) As Long
    Dim lng As Long
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet.Cells) <> 0 Then
        With Sheet
            lng = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                              After:=.Range("A1"), _
                              Lookat:=xlPart, _
                              LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                              SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                              SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                              MatchCase:=False).Row
        End With
    Else
        lng = 1
    End If
    LastOccupiedRowNum = lng
End Function
```

Comment: have you tried adding the worksheet names into your for each loop - at the moment its doing every sheet that is not called Import

Comment: @jimmyshoe where would I define the worksheet names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to run a check to make sure that the sheet names match the ones you want to copy.

Second you need to use `.PasteSpecial` to ensure only values are pasted.

I have updated only the above 2 things in your code below...

```
Public Sub CombineDataFromAllSheets()

Dim wksSrc As Worksheet, wksDst As Worksheet
Dim rngSrc As Range, rngDst As Range
Dim lngLastCol As Long, lngSrcLastRow As Long, lngDstLastRow As Long

'Notes: "Src" is short for "Source", "Dst" is short for "Destination"
Set wksDst = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Import")
lngDstLastRow = LastOccupiedRowNum(wksDst)

Set rngDst = wksDst.Cells(2, 1)

For Each wksSrc In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
 'first change here**
 If wksSrc.Name = "Pro Rate" Or wksSrc.Name = "Weekly Labor" Then
lngSrcLastRow = LastOccupiedRowNum(wksSrc)

With wksSrc
Set rngSrc = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lngSrcLastRow, 9))
'second change here**
rngSrc.Copy
rngDst.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End With
        lngDstLastRow = LastOccupiedRowNum(wksDst)
        Set rngDst = wksDst.Cells(lngDstLastRow + 1, 1)

End If
  Next wksSrc
End Sub

Public Function LastOccupiedRowNum(Sheet As Worksheet) As Long
Dim lng As Long
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet.Cells) <> 0 Then
    With Sheet
        lng = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("A1"), _
                          Lookat:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Row
    End With
Else
    lng = 1
End If
LastOccupiedRowNum = lng
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you!!! this works perfect! just one more thing if you could.. when I run the macro, it does everything correct. But it leaves me at the bottom of the sheet, it didnt do that before. What can I add to make it take me to the top once I run the macro? There is over 40k lines so it will be a problem having to scroll up

Comment: to select cell A1 you would put  Range("A1").Select in your code at the end before you end the sub

Comment: @jimmyshoe after next wksSrc and before end sub i put "Activesheet.Range("a1") but i get an error when running it

Comment: Please can you accept the answer if it has helped? As per JimmyShoe you need `Range("A1").Select`.

Comment: @jimmyshoe quick question.. do you know if its possible to run this macro but have it keep the formulas linked to other sheets?

Comment: @JonathanMarin replace the `Paste:=xlPasteValues` with `Paste:=xlPasteAll`